# What's the package name for PHP7 default?

Tags: apt, php

If I want to install default PHP7 what's the package name in apt-get?

Looking at the package list all I see is php5 and various php-xxxx packages.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: trusty ... 14.04

Comment: 14.04 doesn't have PHP7 in the official repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`php7.0` and a pile of `php7.0-*` packages are available for 16.04-onwards](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Obviously the version might change for future releases, but that's the current nomenclature.

Earlier releases of Ubuntu don't have these. You'd have to compile them yourself or find a PPA. [Ondřej supports all the way back to 12.04 Precise](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) but this comes with the standard warnings and pitfalls surrounding PPAs.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, Ondřej Sury packages PHP for Ubuntu and Debian